# Must declare the scalar variable "@PaperID"

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server

```
 <asp:SqlDataSource runat="server" ID="sdsFormViewPaper"
        ConnectionString="<%$ConnectionStrings:CPMS%>"
        OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}" 
        OnInserted="sdsFormViewPaper_Inserted"
        SelectCommand="SELECT *
                         FROM Paper, Author
                        WHERE Paper.AuthorID = Author.AuthorID
                        ORDER BY PaperID;"
        InsertCommand="INSERT
                         INTO Paper
                            (
                              Active,
                              FilenameOriginal,
                              Filename,
                              Title,
                              Certification,
                              NotesToReviewers,
                              AnalysisOfAlgorithms,
                              Applications,
                              Architecture,
                              ArtificialIntelligence,
                              ComputerEngineering,
                              Curriculum,
                              DataStructures,
                              Databases,
                              DistanceLearning,
                              DistributedSystems,
                              EthicalSocietalIssues,
                              FirstYearComputing,
                              GenderIssues,
                              GrantWriting,
                              GraphicsImageProcessing,
                              HumanComputerInteraction,
                              LaboratoryEnvironments,
                              Literacy,
                              MathematicsInComputing,
                              Multimedia,
                              NetworkingDataCommunications,
                              NonMajorCourses,
                              ObjectOrientedIssues,
                              OperatingSystems,
                              ParallelProcessing,
                              Pedagogy,
                              ProgrammingLanguages,
                              Research,
                              Security,
                              SoftwareEngineering,
                              SystemsAnalysisAndDesign,
                              UsingTechnologyInTheClassroom,
                              WebAndInternetProgramming,
                              Other,
                              OtherDescription
                            )
                       VALUES
                            (
                              @Active,
                              @FilenameOriginal,
                              @Filename,
                              @Title,
                              @Certification,
                              @NotesToReviewers,
                              @AnalysisOfAlgorithms,
                              @Applications,
                              @Architecture,
                              @ArtificialIntelligence,
                              @ComputerEngineering,
                              @Curriculum,
                              @DataStructures,
                              @Databases,
                              @DistanceLearning,
                              @DistributedSystems,
                              @EthicalSocietalIssues,
                              @FirstYearComputing,
                              @GenderIssues,
                              @GrantWriting,
                              @GraphicsImageProcessing,
                              @HumanComputerInteraction,
                              @LaboratoryEnvironments,
                              @Literacy,
                              @MathematicsInComputing,
                              @Multimedia,
                              @NetworkingDataCommunications,
                              @NonMajorCourses,
                              @ObjectOrientedIssues,
                              @OperatingSystems,
                              @ParallelProcessing,
                              @Pedagogy,
                              @ProgrammingLanguages,
                              @Research,
                              @Security,
                              @SoftwareEngineering,
                              @SystemsAnalysisAndDesign,
                              @UsingTechnologyInTheClassroom,
                              @WebAndInternetProgramming,
                              @Other,
                              @OtherDescription
                            );
                       SELECT @PaperID = SCOPE_IDENTITY();"
        UpdateCommand="UPDATE Paper
                          SET Active = @Active,
                              FilenameOriginal = @FilenameOriginal,
                              Filename = @Filename,
                              Title = @Title,
                              Certification = @Certification,
                              NotesToReviewers = @NotesToReviewers,
                              AnalysisOfAlgorithms = @AnalysisOfAlgorithms,
                              Applications = @Applications,
                              Architecture = @Architecture,
                              ArtificialIntelligence = @ArtificialIntelligence,
                              ComputerEngineering = @ComputerEngineering,
                              Curriculum = @Curriculum,
                              DataStructures = @DataStructures,
                              Databases = @Databases,
                              DistanceLearning = @DistanceLearning,
                              DistributedSystems = @DistributedSystems,
                              EthicalSocietalIssues = @EthicalSocietalIssues,
                              FirstYearComputing = @FirstYearComputing,
                              GenderIssues = @GenderIssues,
                              GrantWriting = @GrantWriting,
                              GraphicsImageProcessing = @GraphicsImageProcessing,
                              HumanComputerInteraction = @HumanComputerInteraction,
                              LaboratoryEnvironments = @LaboratoryEnvironments,
                              Literacy = @Literacy,
                              MathematicsInComputing = @MathematicsInComputing,
                              Multimedia = @Multimedia,
                              NetworkingDataCommunications = @NetworkingDataCommunications,
                              NonMajorCourses = @NonMajorCourses,
                              ObjectOrientedIssues = @ObjectOrientedIssues,
                              OperatingSystems = @OperatingSystems,
                              ParallelProcessing = @ParallelProcessing,
                              Pedagogy  = @Pedagogy,
                              ProgrammingLanguages = @ProgrammingLanguages,
                              Research = @Research,
                              Security = @Security,
                              SoftwareEngineering = @SoftwareEngineering,
                              SystemsAnalysisAndDesign  = @SystemsAnalysisAndDesign,
                              UsingTechnologyInTheClassroom = @UsingTechnologyInTheClassroom,
                              WebAndInternetProgramming = @WebAndInternetProgramming,
                              OtherDescription = @OtherDescription,
                              Other = @Other
                        WHERE PaperID = @original_PaperID;"
        DeleteCommand="DELETE
                         FROM Paper
                        WHERE PaperID = @original_PaperID;">
```

Must declare the scalar variable "@PaperID". 
  Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Must declare the scalar variable "@PaperID".

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

> [SqlException (0x80131904): Must declare the scalar variable
>   "@PaperID".]
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception,

Comment: If you don't need the identity value for the insert command just remove "SELECT @PaperID = SCOPE_IDENTITY();" line. If you need the identity value I would suggest using stored procedure for the insert statement. Then If your identity column is integer or long you can return the identity value. If identity is not numeric then you can use output parameter in your procedure and define it in your SqlDataSource Insert Query and read it on the inserted event.

Answer (score 1):

Add below line in the InsertCommand:

```
Declare @PaperID INT -- adding this would resolve your exception

SELECT @PaperID = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
```